# how to send mail into php?

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp

i want solution for send mail into php .
i am using this way send mail 
but getting issue.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

 $to = "xyz@gmail.com";
 $from="xyz@gmail.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject,$from, $body))
 {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
  } 
  else 
  {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
  }
}
```

i am send mail may original id but mail not send 
then browser print the message Email successfully sent!

Comment: do you have mail server configured ?

Answer (score 2):

If you work with WordPress (as your *wordpress* tag suggests), use the [`wp_mail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail) function. If you work with CakePHP (as your *cakephp* tag suggests), use [CakeEmail](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html).

Not only are they easier to use and well documented, but they also protect you from all (or at least many) kinds of exploits. For example, with such simple code as provided in your question, you would quickly turn your contact form into a spam bot, if you'd use posted data without validation/filtering.

Answer (score 0):

use something  with smtp account (using  clean mail  function will give you only problem  )

try this  for example

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail